# prefilling form on a page with a url

Tags: html, url

I'm trying to prefill the form on this following page...

http://brickseek.com/walmart-inventory-checker/?sku=47090529

As you can see I am filling out part of the form via the url, but I cannot manage to fill out the zip when using...

http://brickseek.com/walmart-inventory-checker/?sku=47090529&zip=48446

I assume maybe the site does not want me to do that, but Id like to make it a little easier for myself to fill out the form quicker.

Why is it not allowing me to fill out the zip in the same format? and is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show us the code, how other fields are filling

Comment: Uh, there is no code. Are you sure you understand my post?

Comment: I can't understand, how input type text filled automatically without any code?

Comment: Using sku=47090529 in the first url prefills the corresponding form field. However when I add zip=48446 in the url (second url i provided) the zip does not fill. I assumed you would have figured that out in the info I provided.